# Google AdWords: remove iframe added by tracking conversion code

Tags: google-ads-api

I want to add Google AdWords to my site but the script I'm supposed to add creates an iframe in the dom. This iframe is visible and moves down 13px (its height) all my page.

Is there any way to avoid this? If not, can I hide it without affecting Google AdWords functionality? (It is an empty iframe).

Comment: just ran into this. how is this even a thing? wtf google

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google remarketing tag - iframe height issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18467529/google-remarketing-tag-iframe-height-issue)

Answer (score 94, accepted):

There's an easy fix that doesn't affect the functionality of the code snippet. I've done this with no adverse effects. Just place the script within a hidden div like below and it should do the trick:

```
<div style="display:none">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js">
  </script>
</div>
```

Comment: That seems to be perfect. I didn't know if it would affect the behavior or not. Thanks!

Comment: ...and 3 hours later...so glad I found this...thanks!

Comment: Even if it works, this is not the right way. Using @Adam Hamilton solution is the way to go

Comment: Adam hamilton solution doesnt work anymore. Keep considering this one as the best

Comment: This no longer works. iFrame doesn't render in Chrome.

Answer (score 23):

@Mario is correct that there is a setting that will allow you to turn this display off.  However, this setting doesn't seem to exist on the Google UI for remarketing tags, even though they do display this iframe (I think this is a bug on Google's end, as I imagine the "google_remarketing_only = true" flag was supposed to turn this iframe off and isn't working correctly).

I found out that you can also set this in the tracking JS by manually adding the flag "google_conversion_format = 3", like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    /* <![CDATA[ */
    var google_conversion_id = 0123456789,
        google_conversion_label = "XXXXXXXX",
        google_custom_params = window.google_tag_params,
        google_remarketing_only = true,
        google_conversion_format = 3;
    /* ]]> */
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js"></script>
```

This might be easier that regenerating the tags for some people, and solves the problem in the case that the UI doesn't support setting this option when generating the tags.

Comment: The `google_conversion_format = 3`; definitely fixes the issue.

Comment: This answer should be the validated answer

Comment: This adds an 1x1 image instead of the iframe. It wont fix the issue

Answer (score 18):

I normally add this CSS(3) rule to the stylesheet:

```
iframe[name=google_conversion_frame] 
{
    display: none !important;
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Best solution for me. :D

Answer (score 0):

you can also set max-height: 0; instead of display:none;
Not sure of implications of display none on the iframe.
This works back to ie6.

```
iframe[name="google_conversion_frame"] {
    display: block;
    max-height: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best and simplest solution that I have come across for this issue is simply to remove the frame from the document flow by adding the following code to the css stylesheet:

```
iframe[name="google_conversion_frame"]{
  position:fixed;
}
```

Hope this helps