# Google Tracking Script causing Website Layout issues

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have installed the Google code for Remarketing Tag on my website. I have placed it in the footer of my site. The tracking is working fine, however, I have discovered a piece of the code is causing extra `whitespace` at the footer of my site. The snippet of code causing this is:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js"></script>`

I have tried applying different CSS properties to it, but nothing seems to work. How would I keep the script on the page but it not effect my design?

Comment: Without your relevant HTML and CSS it's nigh impossible to really know what's the issue; can you provide a bit more code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have figured it out:

```
<div style="display:none">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js"></script>
</div>
```

Thanks to this posting: [Google AdWords: remove iframe added by tracking conversion code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11939653/google-adwords-remove-iframe-added-by-tracking-conversion-code)